# How Can I commit Imported Files in Xcode?

Tags: git, xcode4.2

I'm building a new Xcode project in Xcode 4.2 and I would like to use the built in source control. However, Xcode does not provide an option to commit imported files. Is there a setting that needs to be turned on to provide this or is it a bug in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to go into the Organizer (Window > Organizer) and under Repositories, configure your repository or a working copy. Then it'll keep track of file changes automatically and icons will show up to the right of the files in the File Navigator (M for modified, A for added, - for untracked, etc)